# TensorFlow NaN in Output Only When Restoring Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, batch-normalization

I am training a model in TensorFlow that works perfectly when I evaluate from the trained model.

However, at various points, I am saving a checkpoint and then loading that checkpoint to run evaluations on it. The loaded network will just output NaNs.

Using tfdbg and running the filter "has_inf_or_nan" when feeding input ends up showing the first NaNs in the network appearing in the moving_mean and moving_variance variables in one of the batch normalization layers.

Saving is being done with the following code:

```
with self.graph.as_default():
    if not self.saver:
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), max_to_keep=10000)

    save_dir = create_save_dir(path, name)

    return self.saver.save(self.session, save_dir, global_step=iteration, write_meta_graph=True)
```

Loading is being done with the following code:

```
with self.graph.as_default():
    save_dir = create_save_dir(load_dir, load_name)

    self.saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(save_dir + "-" + str(iteration) + ".meta")

    self.saver.restore(self.session, save_dir + "-" + str(iteration))

    self.input_layer = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("network/input_layer:0")
    self.out_policy_layer = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("network/out_policy_layer:0")
    self.out_value_layer = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("network/out_value_layer/Tanh:0")
    self.is_training = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("network/is_training:0")
```

Again, the thing that has me suspecting some issue with my save/load routine is the fact that  the network is outputting valid results if I run through the network that has been trained. I am only getting the NaNs when I run something through a network that was loaded.

Editing to add that my batch norm is being created with the following code:

```
def _conv_block(self, name, input_layer, filter_size, num_input_channels, num_output_channels):
    weights = self._create_weights_for_layer(f"{name}_weights",
                            shape=[filter_size[0],
                                filter_size[1],
                                num_input_channels,
                                num_output_channels],
                            use_regularizer=self._config.l2_regularizer)
    conv = self._conv2d(input_layer, weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", name=f"{name}_conv")
    bn = self._conv_batch_norm(conv, f"{name}_batch_norm")
    return tf.nn.relu(bn, name=f"{name}_act")

def _conv_batch_norm(self, input_layer, name):
    return tf.layers.batch_normalization(input_layer, axis=CHANNEL_SHAPE_INDEX, center=True, scale=True, training=self.is_training,
                                                momentum=self._config.batch_norm_momentum,
                                                name=name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, if you are getting random NaNs in your model, and you have looked at the usual suspects, consider the fact that your hardware could be failing before you waste hundreds of hours.

This was caused by a videocard with dying memory. I assumed we had a software problem, and didn't think of this. The training was happening on a different PC and experienced no issues.

This is how it ended up occurring to us that we had a hardware problem. We previously had experienced randomly occurring NaNs on the old PC. We spent hundreds of hours debugging the model thinking we had an issue. After we made a change we also happened to move to an upgraded PC so we thought our changes fixed it since the NaNs stopped. Then we started running evaluations a month later using that old PC and ran into NaNs again. That is when I posted this. Shortly afterwards I had the realization that there might be a hardware problem.